# How to remove the "Connected to BrowserSync" badge from lite-server in the browser

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm-install

I've installed the John Papa's [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server) NPM package via VS Code console and it's working. But, how can I remove the "Connected to BrowserSync" badge that appears in the browser every time a save a file - and it reloads the file automatically in the browser?

Answer (score 5):

create a config file  `bs-config.js`

and add `"notify": false`

```
module.exports = {
     "notify": false,
};
```

---

if config file location is different from where server starts then specify it

```
lite-server -c path/config-file-name.js
```